# Spark - create list of words from text file and the word that comes immediately after it

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I'm trying to create a pair rdd of every word from a text file and every word that follows it.

So for instance,

`("I'm", "trying"), ("trying", "to"), ("to", "create") ...`

It seems like I can almost use the zip fuction here, if I was able to start with an offset of 1 on the second bit.

How can I do this, or is there a better way?

I'm still not quite used to thinking in terms of functional programming here.

Comment: I should note that I'd like to avoid the mllib sliding function if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manipulate the index, then join on the initial pair RDD:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize("I'm trying to create a".split(" "))

val el1 = rdd.zipWithIndex().map(l => (-1+l._2, l._1))
val el2 = rdd.zipWithIndex().map(l => (l._2, l._1))

el2.join(el1).map(l => l._2).collect()
```

Which outputs:

```
Array[(String, String)] = Array((I'm,trying), (trying,to), (to,create), (create,a))
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. This is starting to make a little more sense now.

Comment: Wait, why does this print out the results out of order?

Comment: @Airhead How so? Anyway remeber that I discarded the index, so you can still order by index (right after join) before using the result.

Comment: I figured it out - I had the arguments to join in the wrong order.